# Sudo error when trying to run a program in the background with bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, sudo, nohup

I have a shell script that makes a sudo program run in the background and then closes the window while the program is still running. Howver I am getting an error when I run it:

Here is what I'm running in the shell:

```
#shell
source ./activate
pip3 install --user package
sudo -v
nohup sudo -S python3 program.py &
```

Then program.py does:

```
import os
os.system("killall Terminal")
programstuff()
```

But an error gets appended to nohup.out saying:

`sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper`

Thanks in advance

Comment: to execute **sudo** command you need to input **sudo password**

Comment: hence u need to run **passwordless sudo command** https://tecnstuff.net/how-to-run-sudo-command-without-password/

Comment: @CYREX It prompts me to enter my password, I enter it, it accepts, and then when running the program.py it gives me that error